# Print permutation of {0, 1, 2, 3} by multithread program (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, permutation

I want print a permutation of {0, 1, 2, 3} set by a multithread program written in C++11.

The source code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;


void func(int index);

int main()
{
    vector<thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        auto var = [&]()
        {
            return func(i);
        };

        threads.push_back(thread(var));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();
}

void func(int index)
{
    cout << index;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++);
}
```

I expect in output a permutation of 0123, but I receive weird results, like these:

> 0223
>
> 0133
>
> 0124

I don't understand this weird behaviour, in particualar I cannot explain the presence of number 4.

Probably this is a beginner's mistake, I thanks anyway everybody will help me.

Comment: [OT]: Instead of `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++);` use a sleep method.

Comment: btw, better way to have a random permutation is by using `std::shuffle`.

Comment: Thank you Jarod42 for your comment, but the real goal for me it's not create a permutation, but to understand the behaviour of this multithreaded process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are capturing `i` by reference:

```
    auto var = [&]()
    {
        return func(i);
    };
```

As such, when the thread that gets eventually started gets kicked off and going, it does not have an actual copy, the value of `i` that it has at this moment, but it has only a reference to `i`.

Which was probably incremented, once or twice now. If you consider that a reference is really just an ordinary pointer with a thin layer of makeup on top of it, you should be able to figure this out on your own. The thread gets a pointer to `i`, which, who knows how many times it could've been incremented, by the time the thread gets going.

And, technically, since `i` could've even gone out of scope here, if the `for` loop terminated before the thread started executing, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right. I think I should use [=] capture instead [&].

Answer (score 2):

You're invoking undefined behaviors in three ways:

Firstly, you're capturing the value of a stack variable by reference rather than by value, so when the thread starts it will call the lambda and use the then-current value of `i` rather than the value at the time of capture.

[edit: No-longer true as of C++11] <s>Second is the thread-safety of cout</s>.

The third is an assumption of the order in which the threads execute which is not guaranteed. [edit:] This includes not only the order in which they start but in which they access `cout` to write their output.

But do you *need* to solve the order of execution?

If you do, then instead of passing the values to the threads, put them into a queue and give the threads access to the queue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>

class LockedQueue {
    std::queue<int> queue_;
    mutable std::mutex mutex_;
public:
    LockedQueue() = default;

    // these don't have to be deleted, but you'd have to decide whether or
    // not each operation needed to invoke a lock, and in the case of operator=
    // you have two mutexes to contend with.
    LockedQueue(const LockedQueue&) = delete;
    LockedQueue(LockedQueue&&) = delete;
    LockedQueue& operator=(const LockedQueue&) = delete;
    LockedQueue& operator=(LockedQueue&&) = delete;

    void push(int value) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        queue_.push(value);
    }
    int pop() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        int value = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop();
        return value;
    }
    bool empty() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        return queue_.empty();
    }
};

void func(LockedQueue& work, LockedQueue& results);

int main()
{
    LockedQueue work, results;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        work.push(i);
        threads.emplace_back(func, std::ref(work), std::ref(results));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    while (!results.empty()) {
        int i = results.pop();
        std::cout << i;
    }
}

void func(LockedQueue& work, LockedQueue& results)
{
    int index = work.pop();
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    results.push(index);
}
```

http://ideone.com/7G0JEO

We are still not guaranteed to get our results back in-order: it's quite possible that the thread that takes `0` off the queue is then pre-empted and doesn't execute again until `1`, `2` and `3` have had their results pushed onto the result queue.

Comment: @M.M Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Sam Varshavchik mentioned about the undefined behavior of the `i` when it when it goes out of scope, i suggest to join each thread created inside the loop where `i` exists by adding this :

```
threads[i].join();
```

And don't forget to remove  the :

```
for (auto& thread : threads)
    thread.join();
```

Your main function should be like this :

```
int main()
{
    vector<thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        auto var = [&]()
        {
            return func(i);
        };

        threads.push_back(thread(var));

        threads[i].join(); // joining the thread after its creation.
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Amrane Abdelkader.

Comment: The thread is so useless... as they are done serially. the vector contains finished thread...

Comment: @Jarod42. if you have any other suggestion i will be thankful.

Comment: I mean your code is mostly equivalent to `int main() { for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) func(i); system("pause");}`